# How to use sort_by or order_by on view and controller with will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, pagination

In my rails application I am limiting the amount of rooms displayed on a page through pagination, I want to allow the user to order/sort the results to different columns of the room model. I think I will need a drop down menu to do this, and then pass this data over to my rooms_controller maybe through an instance variable.

**How can I sort the rooms with the select tag according to a column and what do I need to do in the corresponding controller to make this work?**

At the moment I am using this for a drop down menu:

**index.html.erb**

```
...
...
<%= will_paginate @rooms %>

<div id="order-by">
     <select>
        <option value="asc">Distance</option>
        <option value="asc">Name</option>
        <option value="asc">Price (low to high)</option>
        <option value="des">Price (high to low)</option>
        <option value="asc">Reviews</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
...
...
  def index
    @rooms = Room.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 12
  end
...
```

My room model has listing_name:string, address: string, nightly_price:integer and has_many reviews. My review model belongs_to room. I am using geocoder gem for the location of an room.

I have searched allot and tried multiple things to make this work and I can not figure this one out. For any hints on how to solve this I would be really happy!
If you need further information just let me know.

Comment: Do you want to order elements on the page only or all the entries in Room?
If you want to order all entries you can either refresh page or load values using ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= will_paginate @rooms %>

<div id="order-by">
  <form>
    <select name="sort">
      <option value="distance">Distance</option>
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="price">Price (low to high)</option>
      <option value="price desc">Price (high to low)</option>
      <option value="review">Reviews</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Sort"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @rooms = Room.order(params[:sort]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
end
```

Also need to ensure that `params[:sort]` is included into only available values,
e.g.:

```
 sort = params[:sort]
 sort = nil unless sort.in?(['distance', 'name', 'price', 'price desc', 'review'])
 @rooms = Room.order(sort).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

Consider to use separate scope for sorting or some gem. e.g. [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This helped me allot! I still have to figure out how to make it sort according to the "reviews model" which has the two columns "comment:text" and "stars:integer" and I have to figure out how to work around with the geocoder gem and "distance". But I have a starting point finally! Thank you again! This drove me nuts! ;)